# An error occurred while loading the model. (NotFound) Message: {"Errors":["Owner resource does not exist"]} Databricks model serving error

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

I am trying to understand what is this error message about: [ntkj5] An error occurred while loading the model. (NotFound) Message: {"Errors":["Owner resource does not exist"]}

In my experiment, I have loaded this model and tested it and it works, but for some reason, trying to serve the model gives me this error.

I am using Azure Databricks

Comment: I tried recreating the feature store, and publishing it to a new cosmosdb online feature store since my previous one had 2 extra references to deleted online feature stores.

So then I guess the issue was having several online stores assigned to the feature store. This happened because I published the feature store with the incorrect name, so I published it again with the corrected name and deleted the container with the wrong name.

The problem seems to be that the online store with the wrong name remained attached to the feature store causing the Owner resource does not exist. 

Comment: I am going to leave this here just in case someone faces the same issue. And allow perhaps some engineer from Databricks to elaborate on the meaning of the error message.